# why i am getting this error : IOException parsing XML document from class path resource

Tags: java, spring, maven

Why I am getting this error:

[image: why i am getting this error]

this is my directory structure:

[image: this is my directory structure]

I am using eclips for creating the maven project  and want to add xml file in following line:

```
         ApplicationContext context=new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("com/springcore.collections/collectionconfig.xml");
```

and I don't understand how to set the path. And I am getting following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from class path resource [com/springcore.collections/collectionconfig.xml]
```

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 3):

`src/main/java` is for java files only.

Put the xml into the `src/main/resources` directory, subdirectory accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

you should set your class path like this:

```
ApplicationContext context=new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("com/springcore/collections/collectionconfig.xml");
```